# JWT BearerHandler Token Falied but request is still processed

Tags: jwt, identityserver4, asp.net-authorization

I have run into a very strange problem, and I am guessing that I am missing something in my setup.

I have an WebAPI that is secured by an IdentityServer4. It's only using Client_credentials. If i write the wrong ClientId och ClientSecret that user is not Authenticated, and I can't connect to my WebAPI. But if I write the wrong  scope name the request is still processed and I get my response back, the strange part is that an exception is thrown, but for some reason it's ignored by the .NET Core Framework.

Here are some debug info from my output window.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44360/v1/bookings

```
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Information: Failed to validate the token.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII is hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII is hidden]'.
           at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
           at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
           at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenPayload(JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
           at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
           at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Information: Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII is hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII is hidden]'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware:Information: Executing endpoint 'TRS.BookingService.Api.Controllers.BookingsController.Get (TRS.BookingService.Api)'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "Get", controller = "Bookings"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]]] Get() on controller TRS.BookingService.Api.Controllers.BookingsController (TRS.BookingService.Api).
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method TRS.BookingService.Api.Controllers.BookingsController.Get (TRS.BookingService.Api) - Validation state: Valid
        TRS.BookingService.Api.Controllers.BookingsController:Information: Getting all bookings
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action method TRS.BookingService.Api.Controllers.BookingsController.Get (TRS.BookingService.Api), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult in 96.2159ms.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor:Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String[]'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action TRS.BookingService.Api.Controllers.BookingsController.Get (TRS.BookingService.Api) in 280.2344ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware:Information: Executed endpoint 'TRS.BookingService.Api.Controllers.BookingsController.Get (TRS.BookingService.Api)'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 1345.3829ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

So even that there is an exception thrown that says that the token isn't validated the request is still allowed to continue and execute and the response is sent back to the client.

This is how the ConfigureServices looks like:

```
    services
        .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44392/";
            options.Audience = "FAKE_SCOPE";
        });
```

And the Configure() Methods

```
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
```

This is how the JWT Token looks like:

```
{
  "nbf": 1562062882,
  "exp": 1562066482,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44392",
  "aud": [
    "https://localhost:44392/resources",
    "bookingApi"
  ],
  "client_id": "clientId",
  "scope": [
    "bookingApi"
  ]
}
```

And this is the Client code calling the API.

```
        var idpUrl = "https://localhost:44392/";    
        var clientId = "clientId";
        var clientSecret = "secret";
        var scope = "bookingApi";

        var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenAsync(new Uri(idpUrl), clientId, clientSecret, scope);
        string content = await GetContent(new Uri("https://localhost:44360/v1/bookings"), accessToken);
```

I guess I have missed something when it comes to Authorization, I have tried different

```
services.Authorization()
```

In the ConfigureServices() methods but it doesn't help, guess I have written it wrong.

Best Regards
Magnus

Comment: have you added `Authorize` attribute above your `BookingsController.Get()`?

Comment: Yes, otherwise there hadn't been any authorization done.

Comment: I see your answer. that must not be the expected behavior. the filter (i.e.) the attribute must break the flow. and I'm pretty sure it worked for me as expected. will recheck. what version of asp.net core do you use? they all behave slightly differently

Comment: Yeah I know, it should not be the expected behavior. I am using the 2.2 version.

Comment: created API solution from default template. started "as is": got `200` from http://localhost:57358/api/values. added: `services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;}).AddJwtBearer(options =>{options.Authority = "https://login.dev.xxx.com/"; //options.Audience = "FAKE_SCOPE";});` + `Authorize` on `Values` controller -- got `401` + `WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience is invalid"`.

Comment: probably you have some more authentication scheme registered, i.e. cookie, and it works as a follback one. if that is the case, you need to specify your only allowed scheme explicitly, i.e. `[Authorize (AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer" )]`

Comment: That could be true, I can't find it anywhere. But regardless the only change is that I do an extra check to be really sure that there isn't any Failure at all. So I think I keep my "custom" middleware for now. One issue that could occure is if Microsoft does any changes to it's AuthenticationMiddleware class, then I will never receive them even if I update the packages..

Comment: You are right regarding possible changes in the core. And I suggested just a standard hint, i.e. `[Authorize (AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer" )]`. The decision is  yours : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this article after hitting the same issue. After much banging of head I discovered that it was caused in my case by using services.AddMvcCore() (with .AddJsonFormatters().AddDataAnnotations() in my case) rather than services.AddMvc(). Only with .AddMvcCore() do I get a 401 for token validation failure.

Seems that you need to add .AddAuthorization() to the mix when using .AddMvcCore as it is not added by default. Without it, the token validation fails, but the request pipeline continues quite happily.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a day trying to figure out why it's not working I decided to step-thru the Microsoft code and found this in the AuthenticationMiddleware.

public class AuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

```
public AuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
{
    if (next == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
    }
    if (schemes == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(schemes));
    }

    _next = next;
    Schemes = schemes;
}

public IAuthenticationSchemeProvider Schemes { get; set; }

public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Features.Set<IAuthenticationFeature>(new AuthenticationFeature
    {
        OriginalPath = context.Request.Path,
        OriginalPathBase = context.Request.PathBase
    });

    // Give any IAuthenticationRequestHandler schemes a chance to handle the request
    var handlers = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationHandlerProvider>();
    foreach (var scheme in await Schemes.GetRequestHandlerSchemesAsync())
    {
        var handler = await handlers.GetHandlerAsync(context, scheme.Name) as IAuthenticationRequestHandler;
        if (handler != null && await handler.HandleRequestAsync())
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    var defaultAuthenticate = await Schemes.GetDefaultAuthenticateSchemeAsync();
    if (defaultAuthenticate != null)
    {
        var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync(defaultAuthenticate.Name);
        if (result?.Principal != null)
        {
            context.User = result.Principal;
        }
    }

    await _next(context);
}
```

}

And basically what happends is that the result has a Failure properties on it that contains my authentication exception, but since there is no check for that in the code, it will continue with the request to the next middleware in the pipeline. So I basically wrote my own AuthenticationMiddleware adding a check if the Failure has a value then return 403.

```
        var defaultAuthenticate = await _schemas.GetDefaultAuthenticateSchemeAsync();
        if (defaultAuthenticate != null)
        {
            var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync(defaultAuthenticate.Name);
            if (result?.Principal != null)
                context.User = result.Principal;

            if (result?.Failure != null)
                throw new AuthorizationException(result.Failure.Message);
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
    catch (AuthorizationException ex) when (!context.Response.HasStarted)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning(ex, "Unauthorized access encountered.");

        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
    }
```

It's however not something that would except me to do, so if somebody knows why i need to do this I would be glad for the information.